# problem with Razor syntax and trying to output a string from a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code in a .cshtml file, but each `<option>` is returned with nothing in it.  I have verified the GetDescription() is returning the right string, so I must have a syntax problem in my Razor code.  Can someone tell me what the problem is please?

```
            <select>
            @{
                Array enumValues = null;
                enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchOperatorString));
                foreach (var type in enumValues)
                { 
                <option>
                    @{((Enum)type).GetDescription();} </option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a statement block, which calls `GetDescription`, but does nothing with it's result.

You want to use a code nugget instead, which prints an expression to the page:

```
 @((Enum)type).GetDescription()
```

---

Instead of doing this manually, you should call the `DropDownList` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myName", 
    enumValues.Cast<SearchOperatorString>()
              .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = e })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@foreach(var type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchOperatorString))){
    <option>@((Enum)type).GetDescription()</option>
}
```